# Two Sum solution on LeetCode

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I am currently on LeetCode and am looking through the solutions for the Two Sum problem. Here are the instructions,

**"Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.
You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.
You can return the answer in any order."**

I ran across a couple solutions and I saw this answer:

```
def twoSum(self, nums: [int], target: int) -> tuple:
    num2idx = {}        
    for idx, val in enumerate(nums):
        if target - val in num2idx:
            return num2idx[target - val], idx
        num2idx[val] = idx
```

The part that I am unsure of is this,

```
if target - val in num2idx:
  return num2idx[target - val], idx
num2idx[val] = idx
```

How exactly will this return both indices of the numbers that add up to the target? It looks to me like what is being return is solely the, "target-val" as well as the index of the current num being iterated over.

Comment: Have you noticed that `num2idx` is a dictionary?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes. I see that num2idx is a dictionary and, "return num2idx[target - val], idx" is grabbing the key equal to "target-value".

Comment: It's grabbing the ***value*** for provided key. Now you need to see how is this dictionary populated.

Comment: Before posting, you traced the code, right?  You put in `print` statements to display the variable values, right?  Where are you confused with that output?  Please update your post with that work.  "Teach my this language feature" is off-topic.

Comment: The idea is to get to you to write well-formed questions in the future.
Keep in mind the charter of this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num2idx` is holding the location of each number, not the number itself. The statement

```
 return num2idx[target - val], idx
```

returns the index of the current number, as well as the index of the number that makes up the difference between the current number and the target.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
 let map = {};
 for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
   let compliment = target - nums[i];
   if (map[compliment]) {
     return [(map[compliment] - 1), i];
   } else {
     map[nums[i]] = i + 1;
     }
    }
  };

  twoSum([2, 3, 4],6);
```

Try this code using JavaScript format at Leetcode you will passed...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).